# How can i make this parallax slider to slide automatically

Tags: javascript

I have parallax slider. I want this to automatically slide to end and then slide to beginning. I am new on JavaScript wasted 2 hours by trying.

```
setInterval(changeSlide, 2000);

function changeSlide() {
    var next, prev, slideCount, currentSlide, slideDirection;
    next = document.getElementById('next-slide');
    prev = document.getElementById('prev-slide');
    slideCount = document.getElementById('slider-dots').childNodes.length;
    currentSlide = 1;
    slideDirection = 1;

    if (slideDirection === 1) {
        next.click();
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === slideCount) {
            slideDirection = -1;
        }
    }

    if (slideDirection === -1) {
        prev.click();
        currentSlide--;
        if (currentSlide === 1) {
            slideDirection = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, all you need is to correct your if else logic, also extract your variables initializations out of the function.

By the way I would like to give you an example which could help you improve your logic or rewrite it.

```js
// INIT VARS BY YOUR LOGIC
let currentSlide = 1,
  slidesLength = 10 // GET YOUR .slider-dots,
  direction = 'up';

const animateSlide = (slideNumber, direction) => {
  // HERE YOU COULD CALL YOUR SLIDER API/FUNCTION
  // WHICH ANIMATES YOUR SLIDER, IT IS NOT NEEDED TO SIMULATE CLICK
  // e.g direction === 'up' ? slider.next() : slider.prev() | slider.goTo(slideNumber)
  // WHAT EVER IS YOUR SLIDER API

  // YOU COULD PUT ALSO A LOGIC FOR clearInterval(slideInterval);
  // IN ORDER TO DISABLE THE AUTOMATIC MODE
  console.log(slideNumber, direction);
}

const changeSlide = () => {
  if (currentSlide === slidesLength) {
    direction = 'down';
  } else if (currentSlide === 1) {
    direction = 'up';
  }

  switch (direction) {
    case 'up':
      currentSlide += 1;
      break;
    case 'down':
      currentSlide -= 1;
      break;
    default:
      currentSlide = 1;
      console.error('unknown direction');
  }

  animateSlide(currentSlide, direction);
}

const slideInterval = setInterval(changeSlide, 2000);
```

Comment: ohh exacty what i want hehe thanx a lot i will try this

Comment: BTW, the autosnippet box has a format button that helps you format your code (appears on the right and has "tidy" as its text).

Comment: thanx a lot dudeee woowww hehe I wasted almost 3 hours trying to make this and finally did with your help. thanx a lot

Comment: @ths thanks for the quick reaction,@black I am glad to hear it that you manage to solve it, I will appreciate it if you accept the answer.

Comment: sorry heh i am new here ))